# how to display mathjax formula in with internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, mathjax, joomla3.4

I've developed a website with joomla 3.x in which I've uploaded the mathjax script for displaying formulas. I can see all formula in every browser except with Internet Explorer in my smartphone Nokia Lumia, despite I can see them with IE in my pc.
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I "fixed" it by setting the option of the browser that forces navigation as computer, not as phone.

Comment: You should provide additional details to assist anyone else with the same problem. At present this answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

It's seems to be a browser issue, many other users have the same problem, in particular after the last update of windows phone 8.1.
There's a page about this on github, followed by developers P. Krautzberger and D. Cervone:

https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1085

Some people find out that it renders properly when they switch the phone's browser to desktop mode instead of mobile mode, but it's not a real solution. Developers noticed a similar issue with Spartan/Edge recently, which came down to a bug in handling tags.

Probably the NativeMML output is being selected (incorrectly) for the mobile version. They are doing tests trying to configures IE not to use NativeMML output, or even faking browser detection hoping that this will display properly in mobile mode.